# TeamCity Deployment with Minimum Dependencies

Tags: teamcity, web-deployment, web-deployment-project, webdeploy

We have TeamCity running on a server and our Production site (ASP.NET) running on another Web server. What would be the best way to deploy from TeamCity to the Production server, so that we don't have to install much on the Production server and deployments are fast & secure?

Would Web Deploy (http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy) be the ideal solution?

Comment: Are these servers on the same network?  Can you elaborate on what security you might need when transmitting the bits from the build server to your production server?

Comment: Hi Jimmy, servers are on separate networks/locations. Basic security.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you could have your build script FTP the output of your build to your production server if it's got an FTP daemon running.  SSH would give you more security still.  It's up to you as to how far you want to take it security wise.  I don't use SSH with my blog, for example.  If someone wants to jack with my blog, so be it.

Comment: I would rather use "pull" than "push" for updating the production server - some kind of daemon running there and waiting for new builds to become available (polling TeamCity status periodically over REST). Once they're available, they get downloaded over HTTP, unpacked and installed.

Comment: @Evgeny: Why do you prefer "pull" over "push"?

Comment: Security mostly. I prefer production system downloading artifacts over HTTP and setting them up locally rather than allowing artifacts to be pushed over SSH - it seems to me just trickier to get it right.